# Changing the limits of integration for $ \int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\frac{1}{y^2}}_{\frac{1}{4y^2}} x^2ye^{-x^2y^2}dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\frac{1}{y^2}}_{\frac{1}{4y^2}} x^2ye^{-x^2y^2}dxdy$$

Hi I am trying to compute this integral  but I first need to change the limits of integration, Graphing the limits I get this: [image]

However I am not able to see what region am I exactly looking for when swapping the limits... I can't see what region is bounded by all three graphs.. please help :(

EDIT: I think I got it...

after drawing a vertical strip I get

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}_{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}} x^2ye^{-x^2y^2} dydx $$

can someone check if that is correct

Comment: $$\frac1{4y^2}<x<\frac1{y^2}\iff\frac1{4x}<y^2<\frac1x\iff\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}<y<\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\qquad(\text{because}\ y>0)$$